# OpenGL fails to render scene using Visual C++ compiler

Tags: c, visual-c++, opengl

I am trying to build a hexagon model using OpenGL in Visual C++. I somehow didn't manage to retrieve the correct output.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <math.h>

float x, inc = 3.14/6, pi = 3.14;

void RenderScene()
{   
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    for ( x=0.0; x<2*pi; x=x+inc )
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
            glVertex2f(cos(x),sin(x));
        glEnd();
    }
}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
        RenderScene();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}

void SetupRC(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glOrtho(-5.0,5.0,-5.0,5.0,-5.0,5.0);
}

void main(void)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,15);
    glutCreateWindow("Rofans Manao");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    SetupRC();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Above is my code. My code used to be working previously. I believe I did some unseen mistakes.

Comment: *"My code used to be working"* So, what did you change? In what way is it no longer correct? What do you get now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `RenderScene()` now has the following loop:

```
for ( x=0.0; x<2*pi; x=x+inc )
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glVertex2f(cos(x),sin(x));
    glEnd();
}
```

I think you intend this to be

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for ( x=0.0; x<2*pi; x=x+inc )
{
    glVertex2f(cos(x),sin(x));
}
glEnd();
```

instead, for some form of line strip to appear.